# Using tcpdump, how do I see as plainly as possible an unencrypted SMTP conversation?

Tags: linux, tcpdump

I'm trying to debug an application and it isn't a place that's convenient to run WireShark.

I've been using "tcpdump -nn -x -X port 25" but the output isn't really in the most convenient format. Thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always have tcpdump write out to a file using "-w dump.txt -s 0" as extra arguments, and then load the output file into WireShark locally.

Comment: +1 this is very effective; I do it all the time when I can't run Wireshark on the target system.

Comment: Right, I'd forgotten that WireShark/TShark can operate with the same pcap format that tcpdump does...

Answer (score 3):

`tcpdump -A` (instead of `-X`) will print packet contents in ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

I'd think the easiest thing to do would be to point the application at a SMTP proxy which just passes everything through to the real server and logs it in the meantime (could probably hack something together with [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/) in a few minutes), but going with your current approach...

- Use [TShark](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) to generate a capture file, and load that file into WireShark somewhere more convenient.
- Or use [tcptrace](http://www.tcptrace.org/) on the `tcpdump` or TShark output.
- Or use [tcpflow](http://www.circlemud.org/~jelson/software/tcpflow/).

Answer (score 0):

A utility known as `ngrep` exists which might help you. It has all the power of regular grep, but it works on pcap data. [Check it out here](http://ngrep.sourceforge.net/)